# Create list item if not exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a system where I am tracking some transactions using SharePoint Online.
I have a list where I am pulling all my transactions into.

Form the transactions list, I want to populate two master lists using particular columns from the transactions list.

1. Check if the entity in the transactions list is present in the master list; if not, insert it.
2. Check if a combination of two columns in the transactions list is present in the master list; if not, insert it.

Using Flow(Power automate), how can I check if an item exists in a list?

I will be pulling transaction data using a scheduled flow. So my item copy flow should run after the first one has completed. I cannot have a trigger for item creation in the transactions list.

Answer (score 0):

You will essentially need to:

1) Get the rows from the transactions list

2) Get the rows from the master list

3) Do an apply to each action for the transaction list in part 1

4) Do an apply to each action for the master list in part 2

5) Use a condition to check if the field in the record for transaction list equals the field in the record for the master list.

6) If no, then insert it.

I've used a Sharepoint list and an Excel file in the image below, you can do the same thing with 2 Sharepoint lists.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a sort of `primary key/foreign key relationship` between your transaction list and master lists (let it be 'ID' or composition of two columns) i.e. you can use 'ID' or composition of two columns as  a lookup column in your master lists. Now lets talk about flows,  Once your transaction flow has fetched data, you need to compare this data with items existing in master lists. For this, you can use `Get Items` action in your flow, pointing to your master list. Next you can use `Apply to each` to parse the retrieved properties for items. With in `Apply to each` we can use `Condition` to see if lookup column in your master list equals with corresponding column in transaction list. if `yes`, you create item in master list or run child flow (https://www.serverless360.com/blog/using-run-child-flow-action-to-call-nested-flows) to do the same and terminate the flow. if `No`, let the complete the iteration to check next item in the collection. The screenshot below is just for an idea:
[image]